# Trying to construct a family tree type data structure from scratch, absolutely lost

Tags: java, tree, family-tree

I'm sorry if it seems that I'm coming off as 100% completely clueless; it is not my intention... I truly have tried everything I've learnt so far in my Data Structures course to attempt this project but have ended up getting nowhere and am now seeking help as to how I should go about attempting this.

My final project is to develop the logical & implementation layer of a new data structure that we'll be calling "Family Tree".
In this tree-type data structure each node is a simple node that has the following data values assigned to it: Name, Gender, Date of Birth, Date of Death and Parent (which is a special type of node)

The parent nodes are a special node that contain two sub-nodes, 1 for the father and 1 for the mother, and contain links to 0 or more children and only parent nodes can contain children.

At the very least, I should be able to implement the following methods:

- Create Parent Node: Combine two nodes into one parent node.
- Add Node: Add a new node (family member) to the tree, under a parent.
- Print: Print out the family tree in an informative format.

I have tried everything from adding on to an already existing Tree data structure & creating an object of type Person to store values to be read by each node from the tree to working up my own data structure from scratch.
Out of sheer frustration I've deleted most of my work because it wasn't really going anywhere fruitful.

Any advice on how I can tackle this particular problem?
I wouldn't normally, under any circumstances, post a question to this forum without leaving some of my work but I'm at wits end.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is maybe more of a [Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29). A node should have two parent nodes and 0-n child nodes. The node itself contains the personal info you want. No need for special "parent nodes". Search a bit around the place, there seem to be a lot of similar questions

Comment: While this might be one way to solve this problem, I have to go about solving it the way the professor of my lecture has asked me to do so, albeit him not being too clear, he did mention the use of trees and combining nodes...